# How to improve this google map js code performance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Our current page uses CDN and google map api to show the data. It take around 7 seconds to load the page in total. Google map actually take around 3 seconds to load the page. Here is the snippet of the code I extracted.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                minZoom: 4,
                scrollwheel: false,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.814382, 144.96974),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, myOptions);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.814382, 144.96974),
                title: "120 Collins St, Melbourne, VIC 3000, Australia"
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Here is the screenshot of sites google map api hits.

[image]

We want to improve the performance. Here are several ways I can think of right now, but I am not sure which way should I proceed.

1. Changing the code to be lazily loaded.
2. Use google static map api when page loaded, when user clicked it, use google map api. I think this approach may be too complicated.

May I know additional alternatives to improve the performance of the page

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'd retest without the fonts.googleapis.com call I see there and any other large assets that may be using up local bandwidth while google maps loads.

Comment: @Radio I think fonts.googleapis.com is actually used by the maps api now to load the Roboto font.

Comment: Well that's awful. Anyhow, since gmaps is a massively distributed application, I don't think there's much for improving load time with the code presented by OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to reduce the total number of HTTP requests being made or the bytes transferred when loading the page using the Static Maps API is a good idea, but I would spend more time evaluating the performance before making this leap.

The waterfall you see in Developer Tools may not correspond to the actual time it takes for users to perceive that the Map API is available.  Behind the scenes, the Maps API tries to display a map to users very quickly and progressively load the JavaScript it needs to make that map interactive based on the API calls you need.

Based on the image you've shared above, it looks like significant time is going into doing DNS lookups for each hostname the API is loading from.  I would run some tests [[1]](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/) to see if there are faster DNS servers you could be using.